# How can I RaisePropertyChanged on property change?

Tags: wpf, event-handling, bind

Here I added a model to my viewmodel:

```
public dal.UserAccount User  {
  get
  {
    return _user;
  }
  set
  {
    _user = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged(String.Empty); 
   }
}
```

I handle property change event...

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
  if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
    this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

This is the binding I use:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding User.firstname, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Why the propertychange event is not triggered on updating view?

Comment: You must send your variable name to its parameter instead of `string.Empty`. You can prototype your `RaisePropertyChanged` method as `void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)` and send in to it no parameters, so your caller name will be used to as a parameter value.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PropertyChanged is used to notify the UI that something has been changed in the Model.
Since you're changing an *inner property* of the **User** object - the `User` property itself is not changed and therefore the PropertyChanged event isn't raised.

Second - your Model [should implement the **INotifyPropertyChanged** interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx). - In other words make sure `UserAccount` implements INotifyPropertyChanged, otherwise changing the `firstname` will not affect the view either.

Another thing:

The parameter RaisePropertyChanged should receive is the *Name* of the property that has changed.  So in your case:

Change:
  `RaisePropertyChanged(String.Empty);`

To
 `RaisePropertyChanged("User");`

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx):

> The PropertyChanged event can indicate all properties on the object have changed by using either null or String.Empty as the property name in the PropertyChangedEventArgs.

(No need to refresh all the Properties in this case)

You can read more on the concept of  ***PropertyChanged*** [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx)

Comment: i did that but that doesn't work as in view textbox is bind for User.firstname...

Comment: passing empty string or null will notify all properties of the view model has changed...i believe so...

Comment: @Arun , that is correct but why would you want **all** the bindings in your VM to refresh because of a single property?

Comment: actually i am trying to notify the firstname in user model, which is refer in my VM...but can't figure out what's wrong ?

Comment: may be i am wrong but i need to do check it against my model.

Comment: As I stated, it's an *inner property* of the user, so the setter of user is not called...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25683/discussion-between-arun-and-blachshma)

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke a property changed event from another class. Not particularly useful if you have all the sources. For closed source it might be. Though I consider it experimental and not production ready.

See this console copy paste example:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var a = new A();
            a.PropertyChanged += A_PropertyChanged;
            var excpl = new Excpl();
            excpl.Victim = a;
            excpl.Ghost.Do();
        }

        private static void A_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Event triggered");
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct Excpl
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public A Victim;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public C Ghost;
    }

    public class A : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }

    public class C : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void Do()
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(""));
        }
    }
}
```