# Making a collection of cards visible to other players

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, xaml, visual-studio-2013

My idea is to implement a card game with one server and at least 2 clients. Now I'm stuck at the point where to display the cards in either players hand (one visible, one face-down), the pile of the deck (containing 32 cards) and one pile of thrown cards, so both clients can see them. Whenever a player draws a card/cards, or putting them away, the UI should be updated as well. There is also an system action window, telling players what actions have been made so far, but it does not updating on both clients either.

Since I'm new to c# programming, I really need some advice here, any links are welcome! I already read some articles about the INotifyPropertyChanged and INotifyCollectionChanged, but i can't seem to understand them, i tried many ways and wanted to figure it out myself. This is what i coded so far:

### Clientside

```cs
namespace CardGame.Client
    {
    public sealed partial class gamePage : Page, IPlayerCallback
    {

    ObservableCollection<Card> Hand = new ObservableCollection<Card>();
    ObservableCollection<Card> throwedCards = new ObservableCollection<Card>();
    ObservableCollection<Card> Deck = new ObservableCollection<Card>();
    ObservableCollection<Card> enemyDeck = new ObservableCollection<Card>();
    int switchcase = 1;

    public gamePage()
    {
        login();
        throwable.ItemsSource = throwedCards;
        lstCards.ItemsSource = Hand;
        timerDisplay();

    }


    //OK!
    private async void login()
    {
        await myClient.anmeldenAsync(loginPage.username);
    }

    //OK!
    private async void draw_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Deck.Count != 0)
        {
            if (await myClient.drawCardAsync() == true)
            {
                Hand.Add(await myClient.theDrawingCardAsync());
            }

        }
        switchcase = 1;
        redrawTable();
        showMessage();
    }

    private async void throw_Tapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Card eachItem in lstCards.SelectedItems)
        {
            await myClient.throwingCardAsync(eachItem);

            if (await myClient.canThrowAsync() == true)
            {
                Hand.Remove(eachItem);
                await myClient.throwTheCardAsync(eachItem);

                switchcase = 2;
                redrawTable();
                showMessage();

            }
        }
    }
    private async void showMessage()
    {
        SystemMessage.Text = await myClient.getMessageAsync();
    }

    private void timerDisplay()
    {
        DispatcherTimer countdown = new DispatcherTimer();
        countdown.Tick += countdown_tick;
        countdown.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        countdown.Start();
    }

    public async void countdown_tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        int timer = await myClient.RemainingSecondsAsync();
        Time.Text = timer.ToString();
        redrawTable();
        showMessage();

        if (timer < 6)
        {
            Time.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }

        if (timer > 5)
        {
            Time.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        }
    }

    public async void redrawTable()
    {
        switch (switchcase) {
            case 1:
                Deck = await myClient.leftDeckAsync();
                .....
                break;
            case 2:
                ObservableCollection<Card> thrown = await myClient.thrownCardStackAsync();
                    if (thrown.Count != 0)
                    {
                        throwedCards.Add(await myClient.getTopCardAsync());
                    }
                    ....
                break;  
        }
    }
```

### XAML

```xml
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="1200" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <ListView Name="lstCards" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Height="160" 
    RequestedTheme="Dark" BorderBrush="#FFFD0E0E" Background="DarkGreen" Foreground="#FFFF0A0A" 
    BorderThickness="5,5,5,5" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  Width="650" Margin="150,0,0,0" >
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Canvas VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    IsTapEnabled="True" AllowDrop="True" MaxWidth="800" 
                     DoubleTapped="throw_Tapped">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=Path}" Width="150" Height="150" 
                          MinWidth="150"/>
                    </Canvas>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    <TextBox Name="SystemMessage" HorizontalAlignment="Right" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" 
    VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="405" Height="160" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" 
    FontSize="15" BorderBrush="#FFFD0E0E" BorderThickness="5" IsReadOnly="True" />
</Grid>
```

### Serverside

```
namespace CardGameServer
{
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession,
                 ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant)]
public sealed class Player : IPlayer
{
.....
    public void login(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;

        ICallbackContract callback =
        OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ICallbackContract>();
        if (!callBackList.Contains(callback))
        {
            callBackList.Add(callback);
        }

        game = GameServer.Instance.login(this);
        systemMessage = "Player " + name + " has logged in" + Environment.NewLine + 
        systemMessage;
    }

    //OK!
    public bool drawCard()
    {
        try
        {
            if (GameServer.isTwoPlayer == true)
            {
                drawedCard = game.Deck.getTopCard();

                deckOfPlayer.Stack.Add(drawedCard);

                systemMessage = "Player " + this.Name.ToString() + " has drawn a card." + 
                Environment.NewLine + systemMessage;

                foreach (ICallbackContract callback in Spieler.callBackList)
                {
                    callback.zeichneTischNeu();
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return false;
    }

    //OK!
    public Card theDrawingCard()
    {
        return drawedCard;
    }

    //OK!
    public void throwingCard(Card throwingTheCard)
    {
        try
        {
            game.stackOfThrownCard.Stack.Add(throwingTheCard);
            systemMessage = "Player " + this.Name.ToString() + " has thrown the card: " 
            + throwingTheCard.Color.ToString() + ", " + throwingTheCard.Value.ToString() + 
            Environment.NewLine + systemMessage;

            foreach (ICallbackContract callback in Spieler.callBackList)
                {
                    callback.zeichneTischNeu();
                }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }


    public interface ICallbackContract
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void redrawTable();
    }
```

If there is any more information needed, just tell me.

**UPDATE:** Now i implemented an ICallbackContract on the serverside, and the method redrawTable() on the clientside. But whenever i start the app and try to draw a card, it gives me an error showing following message:

**This operation would deadlock because the reply cannot be received until the current Message completes processing. If you want to allow out-of-order message processing, specify ConcurrencyMode of Reentrant or Multiple on CallbackBehaviorAttribute.**

But why? I already implemented
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession,
                     ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant)]
in the Player class, is there any additional thing to do on the client side?

I read something about delegates, but it is really hard to understand it..

Comment: Could you narrow the question a bit, what exact scenario isn't working, and what pieces of code pertain to that functionality?

Comment: Are you having trouble with updating the UI when items are drawn/thrown? If so then you might want to use RaisePropertyChanged. Here is a couple links of how to use them. Link 2 is more of a mvvm style of tackling this. [Link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246108/how-can-i-raisepropertychanged-on-property-change) [Link 2](http://wilberbeast.com/2010/07/21/wpf-mvvm-and-raisepropertychanged/)

Comment: Thx for the replies! I have troubles with the UI, by creating 2 instances of the same .exe, my server registers them both as clients, and on the other side, my clients can thus calling methods specified for the clients. The problem is that the logic is on the server-side, whenever something happens like a client/player picks a card, the server must provide this information, then not only does the player himself has drawn a new card and taking it into his collection of cards, but the other players can also see whether someone has done an action or not. And that is the problem

Comment: Kudos for trying something so difficult while being new to C#, duplex WCF communication is not trivial to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your server side code, the callback is never invoked to send data back to the clients (assuming you are using a duplex WCF channel, which it looks like you are).

Your callback contract should have a function like "CardDrawn" which would, on the proxy/client side, change a property of your view model in such a way that the UI updates. This could be accomplished through a direct set of a property that calls RaisePropertyChanged, or through event that performs this set. You are already using ObservableCollection, so modifying those collections should also result in a UI update.

Answer to Update:
The error you are getting is due to invoking the callback in a service method. You could change the code so the callback invoke is done on a separate thread (allowing the service method to complete). As the error says, you can specify Reentrant on the **CallbackBehaviorAttribute** to fix this problem also. In your code, it is set on the service behavior.

Here is a MSDN article on Duplex services that might help you, and researching duplex WCF in general would be beneficial: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thx! I knew, i have missed something out there, i have a lot of workaround code, so i need to get to understand with the callback contract a bit more.

Comment: No problem. Remember that the callback contract is just like your standard service contract, except the server is calling functions on the clients (instead of the other way around). Looking at it from that perspective can help drive the contract development.

Comment: This is probably a new question at this point, though I attempted to answer it. The new question should be tagged wcf (duplex if available). It isn't really a problem with VS 2013, WPF, or XAML yet.