# How to add data to a DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, datatable, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

In my solution I create two lists

```
var listColumnNames = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
```

and

```
var listValues = new List<List<string>>();
```

where I add data by iterating over an input dataset. Both lists are built fine and contain the expected data. Subsequently, I use two for-loops to add data to DataTable. The DataTable is instantiated as `private DataTable _selectedFeaturesDataTable = new DataTable();` and later, within the task where I instantiate and fill the two lists from above I write the following after the lists received all data:

```
_selectedFeaturesDataTable = new DataTable();
            foreach (var col in listColumnNames)
            {
                _selectedFeaturesDataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(col.Key, typeof(string)) { Caption = col.Value });
            }
            foreach (var row in listValues)
            {
                var newRow = _selectedFeaturesDataTable.NewRow();
                newRow.ItemArray = row.ToArray();
                _selectedFeaturesDataTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
            }
```

Debugging the code I can see the ItemArray of `newRow` contains the correct data during the iterations, also all values are of type string. Some of the columns in the ItemArray contain empty strings, but I cannot imagine that's the problem.

The line `_selectedFeaturesDataTable.Rows.Add(newRow);` runs trough and looking at the `Rows` property of the `DataTable` I can see the counts increment on every iteration. Yet, the `List` property of the `Rows` in the `DataTable` has still a value of null.

There are now exceptions and no complains, yet the data cannot be found in the `DataTable`, while the columns receive the values from the list.
Also, the component in the UI does not even show the column names.

Finally, here is the way I define the DataGrid in the xaml and the property that I use for the binding.

XAML

```
<DataGrid x:Name="winDataTable" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HeadersVisibility="Column"
                      IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single" AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                      ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedFeatureDataTable, Mode=OneWay}">
```

Property definition

```
public DataTable SelectedFeatureDataTable
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedFeaturesDataTable;
        }
        set
        {
           SetProperty(ref _selectedFeaturesDataTable, value, () => SelectedFeatureDataTable);

        }
    }
```

Why is there no data added to the DataTable object, even though the ItemArray contains values?

Comment: I had similar issues, then i realized that i had to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and when i changed the content of the datasource i had to call the `RaisePropertyChanged()` method

Comment: Hi Leon, I have to stick to the MVVM concept, hence the whole thing should actually work with binding. All my logics should be in the ViewModel and if possible no additional code in the code-behind file.
Would that be possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the MVVM pattern and work with ViewModel-Class instead of code behind, you can try the following approach:

```
public class yourViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged

    public DataTable SelectedFeatureDataTable
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedFeaturesDataTable;
            }
            set
            {
               SetProperty(ref _selectedFeaturesDataTable, value, () => SelectedFeatureDataTable);
               RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

And also, as i know, you can directly bind your datasource in the xaml like this:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedFeatureDataTable, Mode=OneWay}"
```

I never have bind a dataTable, instead i am using ListCollectionView as datasource, but i think that should not matter.

Comment: Hi @TomGeo, you should add the namespace`System.ComponentModel` to your class, then you can use that interface. Yes i saw that you bind like that, but as i know, you dont have to use the word `path=`

Comment: Hi @Leon I altered the way of binding to no avail. The `System.Component` reference is already in the ViewModel, still `RaisePropertyChanged()` does not exist.
What strikes me is, that the DataTable as such stays empty of values in the `Rows` property, while the column names are added to the `Columns` property.

Comment: @TomGeo I am sorry its my mistake, we are using DevExpress and the RaisePropertyChanged() method is in there. But please take a look at this page: [How to: Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface) it is based of the following post: [stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246108/how-can-i-raisepropertychanged-on-property-change)

Comment: Thanks @Leon I will have a look.